# Show that infimum is greater than 0 for a sequence if the sequence is strictly positive and converge to non-zero limit $L$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A=(a_n)$ be a strictly positive sequence converge to non-zero $L$ then show that $\inf A>0$.

My attempt but I don't know how precise is my proof.

Assume for a contradiction that $\inf A<0$ then since $0<a_n$ for all $a_n$, this is a contradiction as $o$ is a lower bounded but $\inf A<0$, which contradicts the definition of being an infimum.

Assume that $\inf A=0$, then $0<a_m<\epsilon$ for some $a_m$. By the definition of convergent to $L$, we have $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N$ such that $\forall n>N, |a_n-L|<\epsilon$.  Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary and $L$ non-zero, we assume that $m<N$. Define $a_p:=\min (a_n)$ for all $n$ between $0$ and $N$ then clearly $a_p$ is another lower bound that is greater than $0$ and hence the statement is proven.

Comment: In the title you say that the sequence is positive. Please edit your post to also put that information into the body of your post.

Comment: There are also some TeX errors in your post, for example L instead of $L$.

Comment: I think it is now better? also I meant inf not lim inf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot say "then $0<a_m<\epsilon$ for some $a_m$" when this $\epsilon$ has not been introduced somehow before. Note that a line later you write $\forall\epsilon>0$, etc.

When the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ with $a_n>0$ converges to some $L\ne0$ then $L>0$. Letting $\epsilon:={L\over2}$ we can say that there is an $N$ with $a_n>{L\over2}$ for all $n>N$. The finite set $\bigl\{a_n\bigm| 1\leq n\leq N\bigr\}$ consists of positive numbers; hence it contains a minimal element $a_p>0$. The number $\iota:=\min\bigl\{a_p,{L\over2}\bigr\}>0$ is a lower bound of the $a_n$ $\,(n\geq1)$ , hence $\inf_{n\geq1} a_n>0$.

Comment: this is much more rigorous than mine! Thank you very much! (But I guess you have to show L>0 first but that is not hard)

Answer (score 0):

Why is it a contradiction that $\inf A < 0$? You need to expand on that point. I would say that this is true because otherwise $\inf A < 0 < a_n$ for all $n$, which contradicts the maximality of the infimum.

Your argument that $\inf A \neq 0$ is correct.

Comment: Thank you but I thought that inf A < 0 is a contradiction because 0 is also a lower bound since the sequence is positive but 0 > inf A and so contradicts the definition of being a minimum? (Sorry if I missed something)

Comment: Yes, you are actually correct. The way it is phrased did not emphasise that $0$ can replace the infimum though, make it a bit clearer. I changed my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ah yes you are right, I should of noted that, thank you!